# jQuery, how can i do to toggle a margin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery-ui;
how can I do a 'toggle' of a 'margin'
first I have '-160px' and then I put '33px '
I want to alternate with each click to '.LoginButton'

CSS

```
.MyBox {
            font-family:Arial;
            color:#FFF;
            width: 400px;
            height: 150px;
            margin-top:-160px;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $('.LoginButton').click(function () {
      $('.MyBox').animate({
           marginTop: '33px'
           }, {
           duration: 2000,
           specialEasing: {
           marginTop: 'easeOutBounce'
           },
           complete: function () {
           }
         });
 });
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty, this *would* work, although I doubt this is best practice.

```
var positiveMargin = false;
$('.LoginButton').click(function () {

    if (!positiveMargin) {
        var marginTop = "33px";
        positiveMargin = true;
    }
    else {
        var marginTop = "-160px";
        positiveMargin = false;
    }
     $('.MyBox').animate({
               marginTop: marginTop
               }, {
               duration: 2000,
               specialEasing: {
               marginTop: 'easeOutBounce'
               },
               complete: function () {
               }
             });
 });
```

Edit: I like zzzzBov's suggestion, but I don't think toggleClass() supports advanced animation such as `specialEasing` or a `completion` callback.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

Answer (score 6):

Or you could use `.toggle()` http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

```
$('.LoginButton').toggle(
  function () {
    $('.MyBox').animate({
       marginTop: '-160px'
       }, {
       duration: 2000,
       specialEasing: {
       marginTop: 'easeOutBounce'
       },
       complete: function () {
       }
    });
  },
  function () {
    $('.MyBox').animate({
       marginTop: '33px'
       }, {
       duration: 2000,
       specialEasing: {
       marginTop: 'easeOutBounce'
       },
       complete: function () {
       }
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple, use `toggleClass` and keep your styles in CSS where they belong.

It'll also allow you to use a selector to determine which animation should be run:

```
$('.LoginButton.foo').animate();
$('.LoginButton:not(.foo)').animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check wether the margin is 33px or -160px, when 33, fade to -160, when -160 fade to 33